# Django Css Issue

Tags: django

I am having a peculiar issue with CSS in Django.

Please see my code below.

```
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
    from Search import settings
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('Search.views',
        # Examples:
        url(r'^$','select_project'),
        url(r'^(?P<Project_Name>[\w \s]*)$','home'),
        url(r'^(?P<Project_Name>[\w\s]*/+\w*)$','Management'),

        url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )

    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
            (r'^(?P<Project_Name>[\w\s]*/+[\w]*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

When my url is `--http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `--http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx/`, my CSS is loading properly.
However, when I navigate from http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx/abcd, then my css will not load. Please help

My Settings looks like this:

```
    MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')

    MEDIA_URL = '/home/'
```

Also, my net console says:

```
[06/Jan/2012 08:56:51] "GET /xxxxx/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1797
[06/Jan/2012 08:56:51] "GET /xxxxx/css/skin.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1797
[06/Jan/2012 08:56:51] "GET /xxxxx/javascript/cufon-yui.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1830
[06/Jan/2012 08:56:51] "GET /xxxxx/javascript/font.font.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1830
```

Comment: How is the CSS rendering? Is it something like `../css/main.css`?

Comment: it renders like /home/css/main.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use relative urls for css (e.g. /your-page/css/main.css).

Use absolute (e.g. /static/css/main.css) instead.

Comment: It worked for me. Cool. however having an issue with loading images from css files. Relative paths not working with Apache. Thank you Vorushin